# WPF C# Binding behaving strangely

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

So I have a c# wpf application with a default layout and different `UserControls` to fill one part of that layout. So far everything worked like a charm with binding properties, but now that i created another `UserControl` the binding only seems to work `OneWay`.

**View -> ViewModel** works great, I can trace button clicks, comboboxes being checked and all that stuff, but ...

**ViewModel -> View** doesn't want to work at all.

I've tried setting the Mode of the Bindings to `TwoWay` and setting `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`, but nothing changes.

This is my View:

```
<UserControl ...
      xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Prueftool.BBCCreatorViewModel"
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:CreateDisplayTypeViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" Width="75" Command="{Binding TestButtonClick}"/>
        <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding TestIsChecked}"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here is my referenced ViewModel:

```
namespace Prueftool.BBCCreatorViewModel
{
    class CreateDisplayTypeViewModel : ViewModelBase, ICreateDisplayViewModel
    {

        private bool _testIsChecked;
        public bool TestIsChecked
        {
            get { return _testIsChecked; }
            set
            {
                _testIsChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TestIsChecked");              
            }
        }

        public void SetNewDisplayType(DisplayType selectedDisplayType)
        {

            if(selectedDisplayType.Name == "Default")
            {

                TestIsChecked = true;    
            }

        }


        private DelegateCommand _random;
        public ICommand RandomButtonClick
        {
            get
            {
                if (_random == null)
                {
                    _random = new DelegateCommand(randomButtonClick);
                }
                return _random;
            }
        }


        private void randomButtonClick()
        {
            if(TestIsChecked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
            }
        }

    } 
}
```

The `SetNewDisplayType` method is being called and the if statement is true, but it won't check my combobox in the view. On the other hand, checking the combobox manually and then pressing the button fires the `randomButtonClick` method and a MessageBox appears.

EDIT:

OnPropertyChanged method (not mine)

```
#region public virtual void OnPropertyChanged()
        /// <summary>
        /// Raises this object's PropertyChanged event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">The property that has a new value.</param>
        public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            this.VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);

            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

Comment: Perhaps your OnPropertyChanged has a problem? If it works correctly bindings should work.

Comment: that's the thing, I haven't touched it, and everything worked just fine up to today.

Comment: And you're sure the if statement evaluates to true? You stepped through with the debugger to verify that?

Comment: @AlexPaven yup, did exactly that. Set a breakpoint before and stepped through it with F10.

Comment: iam not sure but is the statement `if(TestIsChecked)` ok? dont u miss sth like `TestIsChecked = sth`in the if statement?

Comment: @Raizzen should be all good, if i check the box manually, it steps into the if-statement.

Comment: @AlexPaven added OnPropertyChanged() to the post

Comment: As a general note, a UserControl should never have its "own" view model, i.e. explicitly set its DataContext property. Instead, it should expose properties that are bound to properties of an "external" view model. The DataContext value is therefore inherited from one of the parent elements of the UserControl, e.g. the MainWindow.

Comment: Turn on WPF tracing and see if the bindings complain about anything - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409960.aspx, I think I'm out of ideas otherwise

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be calling SetNewDisplayType on a different instance of CreateDisplayTypeViewModel than the one used as DataContext. The binding works and the checkbox is checked when I use your UserControl and change the Constructor to

```
public MyUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ((CreateDisplayTypeViewModel)DataContext).SetNewDisplayType();
}
```

and `SetNewDisplayType` to

```
    public void SetNewDisplayType()
    {
            TestIsChecked = true;    
    }
```

It would help though if you could post how this function is called.

Edit: The fact that the handler in OnPropertyChanged is null (as you mentioned in the comments above) is also a hint that you might be using two instances of the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to implement *INotifyPropertyChanged* on your class.

```
class CreateDisplayTypeViewModel : ViewModelBase, ICreateDisplayViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

I see you have the *OnPropertyChanged* method but you would also need to implement to *PropertyChangedEventHandler*. Something like this should do it:

```
#region Public Events

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion Public Events

    #region Protected Methods

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    #endregion Protected Methods
```

Comment: I'd bet that ViewModelBase already implements INotifyPropertyChanged, so there's no need to declare it again. There's also a reason why OP's implementation of OnPropertyChanged assigns  PropertyChanged to a local variable `handler`. Nowadays you would write `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));` anyway.

Comment: @Clemens Yeah, I would bet the same typically. Just not obviously and so worth checking.

Comment: @Clemens yeah, you're right, the weird thing is that the handler varialbe in OnPropertyChanged is still null after its should be assigned in this line: PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;

Comment: @spacebarisdefect Are you sure you're debugging the correct instance of the view model class? As already said, explicitly assigning the UserControl's DataContext is generally wrong, and often the source of confusion when there is another, "actual" view model.

Comment: @Clemens I'm pretty sure it is. I've created some new namespaces, can it be that these may cause the issue?